# Synchronization of new data with previous data

Tags: java, android, synchronization

I am working with synchronization for the first time. I wrote some code that I have to implement in my current work. I wanted to know if I am doing it right or am I making a mistake.

Whenever a new list of data is downloaded, `NewDataArrived()` is called. This method then calls the `ListData()` that returns the list of previously saved data. There is another class running in parallel that uses the `ListData()`. What I want to do is whenever the List is being updated, the Thread class should just wait until the list is updated.

```
public class ListData() {

/*
*
*




*/
public List < name_holder > getList() {
    synchronized(LOCK_LIST) {
        if (newDataArrived)
            LOCK_LIST.notifyAll();

        return full_list;
    }
}


void NewDataArrived() {

    newDataArrived = true;
    parallelDownload p = new parallelDownload();
    p.start();
    getList().addAll(my_list);
    newDataArrived = false;


}

class parallelDownload extends Thread {
    private Object o = new Object();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(o) {
            for (name_holder n: getList()) {
                while (newDataArrived) {
                    try {
                        o.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! If I might recommend one very quick step to make your code formatting/indentation better, is to just copy the code into a code beautifier (a JavaScript or PHP beautifier works fine for Java as well - I often use http://jsbeautifier.org/ for Java code)

Comment: You explained what you are trying to do but I still don't understand. What is `parallelDownload` supposed to do? The `newDataArrived` variable isn't accessible in `parallelDownload`. What is `getList()`? Sorry, but this code looks rather messy and confusing and it's hard to make sense of it.

Comment: Solomonoff's Secret .. The parallel download gets the information from the list and uses that information to perform network related things. I am sorry, i forgot to put than in the code above.

Comment: Please avoid updating your code after you've received answers. This invalidates said answers. Read _What to do after receiving answers_ on the help page for more information.

Answer (score 1):

**Coding Conventions**

First of all: You should follow common naming conventions for Java.  It makes it harder to read your code if you don't -- or to put it differently: It is easier to help if the code does follow common conventions.  Maybe have a look at [Google's Java Style](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html) or at least:

- write methods in `lowerCamelCase` style and
- classes in `UpperCamelCase` style.

Furthermore it would be good to provide a compilable minimal example.

**Threadsafe List**

From what I understood you want to have a list which is capable of being accessed and modified from multiple threads.  If so, you may have a look at [this stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203864/the-best-concurrency-list-in-java).

**Java Concurrency**

Some general things:

1. You don't need to instantiate an object for your `synchronized` blocks.  If you do not specify an object, the current object is used.  That should be sufficient for your use cases.
2. Don't `start` a thread directly.  Rather use an [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) instead.
3. Don't subclass `Thread`, but rather use a `Runnable` (also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread)).
4. Very good book on the whole topic: *Java Concurrency in Practice*.